# Python MVC framework for desktop applications

Tags: python, frameworks, mvc, desktop

I'm used to program with Python and GTK using pygtk library.

I feel like my programs are not well separated according to MVC model.
I think following a framework it would help me to design better desktop
applications.

I'd like to know which Python MVC framework for desktop apps you're using and
why.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a framework. Create a class called `Model`, another one called `View` and a third one named `Controller` and start coding. Put all of the UI code in the `View` class, your data structures in the `Model` class, and make sure they communicate only via the `Controller`. I think going through that exercise might teach you a lot.

I'm not trying to be funny here, it's really not very complicated, and doesn't require a fancy framework.

Comment: A single class in any container there is probably going to be a horrible practice given any nontrivial program.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying to create _only_ three classes. That's just a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

first, I think Qt, and even it's Python bindings are *way* better structured than GTK; so you could first try it.

second, it seems you're slightly confused by the MVC buzzword.  It was originally defined as a **modular architecture for GUI applications**; unfortunately, there's a completely different **layered architecture for Web apps** also called MVC.

Maybe you feel your desktop apps are not very MVC because there not very *web MVC*, but they might be very *GUI MVC* nonetheless.

Comment: +1 for Qt, I'd recommend PySide instead of PyQt4.

Comment: -1 for Qt. Not because I dislike it -- I've never used it -- but because a personal opinion on a choice of tool doesn't address the question being asked IMO. That, and toolkit wars, like editor wars, are so tiresome. Also -1 because this is the first time I've ever heard of "web mvc". To say there is somehow a distinction without giving any information to back that claim up isn't very useful.

Comment: so you're downvoting because you don't know what i'm talking about, right?

Comment: @Javier: no, I'm down-voting because you said things that didn't make sense, and you didn't provide any facts or references to back up your statements. Bottom line: in my opinion, nothing in your answer is at all helpful to the person who asked the question. If you take the time to describe exactly how these two definitions of MVC are so completely different, your answer might be very enlightening and useful. As it stands, it's just adding to the confusion.